# Interface call-back method not being called?

Tags: android

I am working with an Android project. Here is what you need to know for my problem. (Let me know if its not enough):

I have a fragment , an async task, and an interface named async response. Async Task live in its own class and is called DownLoadRawData. Here is the code for the fragment:

```
   public class RedditListFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncResponse{


   private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
   private RedditAdapter mAdapter;
   private Parser parse;





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reddit_list, container, false);
          mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.reddit_list_view);
          mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));





        executeAsyncTask();





    updateUI();
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}


**@Override
public void processFinish(String output) {
    parse = new Parser(output);
    Log.d("TAG", "The List to STring is " + parse.getRedditObjectList().toString());
    Log.d("TAG", "process finished reached");
}**

public void executeAsyncTask(){
    DownLoadRawData downLoadRawData = new DownLoadRawData();
    downLoadRawData.delegate = this;
    downLoadRawData.execute("https://www.reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/.json");


    // Log.d("ERR", " TEXT WAS "  + jsonTEXT);
}






public void updateUI(){
        List<RedditObject> listOfRedditObject = parse.getRedditObjectList();

        mAdapter = new RedditAdapter(listOfRedditObject);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}




private class RedditHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    private TextView mTextView;


    public RedditHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextView = (TextView) itemView;  //by casting itemView to a TextView, this forces client to pass text view
    }

}


private class RedditAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RedditHolder>{


    private List<RedditObject> mListOfRedditObjects;



    public RedditAdapter(List<RedditObject> listOfRedditObject){
       mListOfRedditObjects = listOfRedditObject;
    }

    @Override
    public RedditHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_reddit_listing, parent, false);
        return new RedditHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RedditHolder holder, int position) {
            RedditObject redditObject = mListOfRedditObjects.get(position);
            holder.mTextView.setText(redditObject.getmTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return mListOfRedditObjects.size();
    }
}
```

}

The DownloadRawData Async Task class is here:

```
package com.example.ridhwaan.redditforfaez;

  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.util.Log;
   import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
  import java.net.URL;


public class DownLoadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private String mFileContents;
    **public  AsyncResponse delegate = null;**




public String getmFileContents() {
    return mFileContents;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    mFileContents = downloadRawJSON(strings[0]);

    return mFileContents;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    **delegate.processFinish(result);**
    Log.d("TAG", "RESULT" + result);


}
```

And the Aync Response:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {

void processFinish(String output);
```

}

For some reason, in my fragment class, the process finish method is not being called. From my understanding of interfaces, the Async Response is implemented in the DownLoadRaw data class with the parameter supplied. Then we set a delegate to this in the fragment class so it can be ready to get the method results back , or  call back. Please help me with my understanding if its flawed.

The problem is the process finish method is not being called at all. The Logs that I put are not being printed out but they are being printed out everywhere else.

What could be the cause to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should printed log if `onPostExecuted` be called. Check the log in `onPostExecuted` if it is called or not.

Comment: The Log is OnPostExecute does not seem to print

Comment: Maybe `DownLoadRawData ` task was not running. Try to execute by command `new DownLoadRawData().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR); `

Comment: Threadpool is a bit of overkill/inefficient unless he modifies his code to take advantage of the concurrent feature. As is it looks like he is only attempting to run a single thread. And if that is the case a simple thread + callback might be the easier answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should instead have your activity be the one that is called, then have the activity notify the fragment of any changes. Have the activity store a reference to the fragment via that interface.

[Model View Presenter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) helps a lot when dealing with fragments and concurrency. (Just a helpful tip)

But to answer your question: you don't need to call Super() in onPostExecute(). It is most likely halting execution at that point. So if you delete that line you'll probably be alright.

(Assuming your **psuedocode** lines actually work, since you didn't show the full code)

Comment: It seems my OnPostExecute is not running. The Log in the method does not execute. How do I fix that problem?

Comment: AHH... I ran into this once... are you rotating your phone during the test? Because, that causes a disconnect between the Fragment & Activity and between the asyncTask.

What you should do is log your doInBackground and see if every few operations it continues to operate. It could be that it is crashing/throwing exception (Which I believe is thrown away completely when it happens there but not sure offhand) but either way.... See if doInBackground is even completing first, then worry @ onPostExecute.  

But as an FYI, headless fragment is how we've found to store asyncTask vs rotation/etc.

Comment: https://github.com/douglascraigschmidt/LiveLessons/blob/079b30981156fca1001edfd8f73c8fcf99b4c290/ImageTaskGangApplication/src/example/imagetaskgang/MainActivity.java#L48 here is an example of the HaMeR framework in Android (Doug & I named it such(mostly Doug)) where it shows a much easier way to do a single thread running in the background. this might be clearner than AsyncTask. But, either way you need to see if your network calls are actually running and processing properly.